# Operating systems for MCUs that use system calls to abstract away interaction with device peripherals

Tags: operating-system, microcontroller, cortex-m, rtos

This question is a reference request.

Typical embedded operating systems like [mbedOS](https://www.mbed.com/en/platform/mbed-os/) or [FreeRTOS](https://freertos.org/) don't use system calls (e.g. [supervisor calls](http://www.keil.com/support/docs/4063.htm) in ARM cores), or only use them to provide a very small subset of core OS features like scheduling. Some OSes provide a [common API](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.12/apis/index.html) to interact with device drivers and peripherals; device manufacturers implement these APIs to work with their specific device, and users link their application code against these when they want to interact with the device.

I'm looking for operating systems for microcontrollers that use system calls to also abstract away interaction with device peripherals, and what their uses might be. In this scenario, users link their application code with a header file exposing the API, with methods like e.g. `set_gpio_interrupt_handler(uint8_t pin, void (*func))`. These trigger a system call exception, which is then handled in the kernel to provide the device-specific functionality.

I don't know of any OSes that work under this scheme to interact with device peripherals. The main advantage of doing it this way is that users can compile their code separately from the kernel, so they wouldn't have to recompile the whole thing if only the kernel or the application is updated. Application binaries would be more lightweight and could be transferred to the MCU via a USB bootloader instead of having to be flashed with a programmer. What other advantages, uses, and disadvantages are there / could there be of such an OS?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "embedded" but Linux works this way. See the Raspberry Pi as an example. The application does not even have to be machine code. I have a robot that runs on javascript communicating with device drivers written in C. And indeed my applications are lightweight - I transfer them over ssh without needing to reboot the machine

Comment: Most embedded systems are a co-development of software and hardware; the OS does not deal with peripheral devices because the platform is not a general purpose or standardised design and the peripheral set varies widely from design to design. Moreover, especially in real-time systems, the developer needs precise control of the implementation, behaviour, performance  and timing of device drivers.  A generalised interface may not always meet those constraints.  In fact that in my experience is what makes efforts such as mbed and STM32Cube unsuited to many hard real-time applications.

Comment: The application might be more lightweight, but the kernel would be larger. VxWorks supports the separate loading of object code (the runtime dynamically links object code to the kernel - so not quite what you describe, but with similar benefits).

Comment: You can use a USB bootloader to load monolithic standalone code to flash - that does not require a hardware programmer - other than to load the initial bootloader perhaps and many MCU have one in make ROM in any case.  I have written a bootloader for STM32 that supports UART, USB, SD card and CAN bus.  The benefits you perceive as coming from GPOS architecture can (and are) be achieved by other means in many embedded systems.